# How to make turtles move at the same time?

Tags: model, netlogo

I'm modeling a bus stations with passengers. When all the passengers of a bus station are boarded, I want the bus (a turtle) to drive away. This should happen at the same time, however it is not at the moment. The buses leave after each other. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It still all happens in the same tick, so that is pretty much simultaneous since they don't have any effect on eachother. The only effect "leaving together" would have here is visual. If you really want them to move together you should use a link to group them together and then use `tie` so that their movement is linked, or create a loop with them all taking very small steps in succession.

Some more remarks:

- By the way what is the purpose of the `time` parameter? Why not just use `ticks`?
- You are calling `tick` twice. Once in `go` and once in `drive`.
- The `if` usage still feels really weird in your `check-in` procedure, especially since you combined it with `move-to`.
- The `neighbor` usage is also still weird. Why not a construction with `patch-here`?
- Constructions like `one-of patches with [pxcor = 3 and pycor = 8]` could be rewritten much more conveniently as `patch 3 8`
- I still suggest making a separate breed for your passengers.
- The naming of the bus breed still feels very off, since you are using the singular bus as plural

(I am deliberately not giving any actual code as answer since this series of posts feels very much like a school project)

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answers.
- If I use 'ticks' instead of 'time' the code somehow doesn't work. It might be extra, but at least it works like this.
- Also when trying the patch-here command, the code didn't work. My code might not seem very logical to you, but I'm also really not experienced in it. And I find it very difficult to understand. Therefore, I also write out the whole 'pxcor = 3' it makes it more clear to me.

Comment: You are indeed right about the fact that everything happens in the same tick. However, if I play the code very slowly you see a difference between the buses, and this is an issue. They have to make at the same time, even when playing the code slowly. I tried to make it work with 'tie', but I keep failing in it. It's indeed a school project, and I really spend a lot of time on it. But as I said I find it very hard. Would you please be willing to help me? I adjusted some things in the code, as you suggested.

Comment: For a `tie`, you need to do only 2 things. The first part is making sure that the busses have a connection to eachother. `create-links-with` is perfect for that. (make sure you only let them make links with the other busses, as you can't link to yourself).

Comment: The second part is then to make sure that the link ties the busses together. For that you ask the links to `tie`, which is really all there is to it.

Comment: Regarding the bus breed... Now you put them down in reverse order.  Netlogo expects the first part to refer to the agentset of the entire breed, and the second part to refer to a single turtle of that breed. So `breed [busses bus]`. That would also change `create-bus` to `create-busses`, which corresponds with the standard `create-turtles`

Comment: Are you sure you are using `ticks` instead of `time` and didn't accidentally use `if tick = 1` ? It is very easy to confuse `ticks` and `tick`

Comment: Thanks again! I adjusted my code again and I realized that something was wrong with my initial idea. The busses don't need to drive off at the same time. The idea is that the passengers (grey turtles) all start moving at the same time, with different speeds, and when all passengers are gone from a station (white patches), the bus should leave. In this way the busses should leave in different times. So, I tried to link the passengers, but it is not fully working (see code above). Do you maybe see what I did wrong?

Comment: @DwayneJohnson I wouldn't use tie to move the turtles at the same time. Tie would work for them all moving in the exact same direction at the exact some time. To be honest I would never use it for the busses either but since it is an assignment, with not necessarily optimised requirements, it seemed fitting there.

Comment: You also use a very unfortunate construction where you `ask links[ask turtles[...]]`
In this construction, every single links commands every single turtle to do something, not just the turtles they are connected to. There are commands for that but you would have to look those up in the dictionary. But never mind that, the problem is just the structure.

Comment: If you want them all to move simultaneously but at different speeds, I would still suggest letting them all take a very small step in the direction of the bus, then letting them take another very small step etc. The size of those steps would differ between the different speeds you want. Check [View updates] in the programming guide for how you can manipulate the view so that it looks like everything happens simultaneously(https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#view-updates) (tip: it involves Tick-based updates and `display`)

Comment: Thank you very much again! With help of your tips I have changed my code substantially (see my code above). The people now check-in how I want it. I do, however, have 1 problem left. At the moment, all passengers from all platforms first check-in. After that the busses leave in the order that I gave them (see 'to drive'). However, I want a bus to leave when the platform is empty. So, regardless of what the other buses/passengers are doing. Do you have any idea how to code this? I tried and looked up different things, but I can't figure it out ...

Comment: Well, currently the passengers still all check in simultaneously as far as your code is concerned, since you only run check-in once. I assume each turtle reaches the bus within that one iteration of check-in? With that in mind it makes sense that the busses leave at the same time. Now if you were to work with some sort of loop where it is possible for a turtle to move but NOT reach the bus immediately, then you can let each bus check at the end of each iteration if it is ready to leave.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I see what you mean. The turtles indeed all reach the bus within one iteration. I actually already tried to create what you are saying, however I really got stuck. Do you have any example how to do this maybe?

Comment: @DwayneJohnson I edited an example in

Comment: @DwayneJohnson Editted it back out and wrote it down as answer to your other question, where I feel like it is more relevant